# Select data from DB using RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I need advice for design pattern how to use RabbitMQ to select data from Database.
RabbitMQ looks very good solution for inserting and updating data into Database but what about selecting data from DB?

In my case I have REST API module and Database module connected to Maria DB which communicate via queues.

```
REST API module -> Database module -> Maria DB
```

But I need to select configuration from database via database module. I can use RPC as a solution but probably there is better way?

Can you advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, some sort of [RPC](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html) is the way to go.

However: The point of a queue (asynchronous tasks) is the opposite of a database select (return my data now). If the direct database select requests are performing adequately, use them, avoid the extra complexity. Or some caching system for your config. This might not work for your system architecture and load needs, but is simpler.